# How does angular inject component specific styles into <header> tag of the html? is there way to package css into files

Tags: html, css, angular, view-source

Angular application:
Opening viewsource html in the browser, it's dynamically adding inline style css tags  as we browser cross different components in the page.  Why does angular do this (lazing loading)? is there a way to separate it out rendering in a separate css file ?

Comment: are you looking for solution or ..? to understand the basics. If you have some errors then post the code. someone can help you out.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, I'm not sure what you're saying but I will explain the basics to you.

Angular relies on webpack to bundle your application.

When it bundles it, it does two things for CSS files :

1 - Get the files in the `styles` array of your `angular.json` file and builds a CSS chunk for your application (that is then added to your `<head>`

2 - Bundles every component-specific style into a JS chunk that can be lazy loaded.

This means that your global styles are loaded when the page is loaded, but the lazy loaded module styles are loaded only when the said module is being loaded.

If this isn't clear or doesn't answer your question, please let me know.

Comment: It does. Thank you